# אין כערכך ואין זולתיך - a mistaken addition?

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, shabbat, shacharis-morning-prayer, bircas-krias-shema

In Shabbos Morning Davening, we read:

> **אין כערכך ואין זולתך אפס בלתך ומי דומה לך**. **אין כערכך** ה' אלוקינו בעולם הזה **ואין זולתך** מלכנו לחיי העולם הבא. **אפס בלתך** גואלנו לימות המשיח **ואין דומה לך** מושיענו לתחיית המתים.

I had recently been saying this, when it occurred to me that the first sentence seems to be a hybrid of the following 4 phrases, as bolded above.  I was wondering if someone has proposed that the first sentence, אין כערכך ואין זולתך אפס בלתך ומי דומה לך, was a shortened form of the following sentences, or if it may have been originally printed in a siddur as אין כערכך etc. ואין זולתך etc. אפס בלתך etc. ומי דומה לך etc., and the other verses were not present.

Do any siddur commentaries comment on this sentence in a similar fashion?

Comment: ArtScroll claims that the paytan wrote these four phrases, then in the next sentence expanded on what he meant by them. A similar thing appears in Nishmas - הקל הגדול הגבור והנורא קל עליון קונה שמים וארץ...הקל בעצמות עזך הגדול בכבוד שמך הגבור לנצח והנורא בנוראותיך המלך היושב על כסא רם ונשא. That one isn’t as obvious because there’s another sentence in the middle, plus most Siddurim print a paragraph break there. I don’t remember if they quoted anyone, but if they did, free answer for somebody.

Comment: @DonielF R' Hirsch

Comment: This seems just like normal poetic parallelism.

Comment: @DonielF Thanks. Feel free to take the credit and post as an answer.  Although Nishmas seems a little different due to the continuation being absent (קל עליון קונה שמים וארץ)

Comment: @DoubleAA OK, examples please?

Comment: פסח. מצה. מרור.

Comment: @DoubleAA that's a stretch... If we're already going to the Haggadah, I would better compare it to the darshening of Arami Oved Avi.  But I do get it, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*T'fila L'Moshe* by Rav Aharon Lopiansky quotes [Rav Y'huda ben Yakar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_ben_Yakar) as linking the two components in this way, with each later line being an explanation of its preceding word pair(+) (emphasis mine).

> אלו ארבעה לשונות נאמר כנגד ארבע עולמות שהוא אדון יהיה לכולם, **ובא המתפלל לפרשם**

Akin to DonielF's and DoubleAA's suggestions, it seems to be a common deliberate structure - in which an opening itemization is expanded upon piece by piece - even in non poetic contexts.

- It closely resembles the structure of many opening *mishnayos* (like [these two](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%90_%D7%91) and [these two](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%96)).
- And see the bottom of [Zevachim 2a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Zevachim.2a?lang=he), top of [Rosh Hashanah 4b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rosh_Hashanah.4b.1?with=all&lang=he).
- Additionally, see the beginning of [chapter 19 in M'silas Y'sharim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Messilat_Yesharim.19.1) for an explicitly list oriented version of the same style.

Comment: Re your final point about Mishnayos, don’t forget masechtos like Bava Kamma where you have one Mishnah which is elaborated upon across the next several Perakim, not just Mishnayos.

Comment: @Shmuel Which line are you referring to in ר"ה? And in זבחים are you talking about the איבעית אימאs?